# Open the View over the other not as a subView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I want to overlap view over the another view. I don't want to add it as a subView. The new view should be added with following rect size (280,400) on the super view of size (320,460).

Can any one suggest me the right way for doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by use of UIAnimations, replacing one view with the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could add both view as subviews of a superview. And the superviews view controller handles the show and hide of the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what you mean, but i will try...

**Overlapping == Changing "z-index"**

You can use the following to bring your view above the other views it shares its hierarchy with.

```
[yourview.superview bringSubviewToFront:yourview];
```

**Overlapping == adding to the superview**

Then this should do the trick.

```
UIView *yourview = ???
yourview.frame = CGRectMake(?,?,280,400);
[self.view.superview addSubview:yourview];
```

Any UIView or variation thereof can respond to the .superview. Its a global "where the heck am I ?"

If you want to go all the way to the uppermost layer, there is also :

```
[self.view.screen addSubview:yourview];
```

You can't get much higher than that ;]